# Emulate Li-ion battery using a charger

Tags: lithium-ion, charger, ipad

I bought an iPad with dead battery (it’s bulged). When I connect it to a charger, the only result is a boot loop (Apple logo, blink, Apple logo, blink…).

I want to use it as a kind of picture frame, which would necessitate constant charging anyway, so I’m reluctant to buy a replacement battery that will be of no use and dead again within few months because of constant charging.

I am thinking that it should be possible to solder a charger into battery circuit (disconnecting the battery, of course) to trick iPad into thinking it actually has a battery connected.

Do you know any examples of this?

Comment: *Do you know any examples of this?* Yes, on an Oppo smartphone I removed the battery and connected the +5V line from the USB connector to the + of the battery input (after confirming the USB GND and battery - were already shorted). But yours is an Apple product and therefore different. What I did might not work, the iPad might need more than just a battery voltage being present. You will just have to try and see.

Comment: Most likley you will need a battery for it to function. If you are up for it you should be able to substiture it for something else of the same voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've experienced was with my laptop. At some point the battery died and the laptop started misbehaving (rebooting, not starting etc.) I removed the battery and use it only on charger now and have no issues. Note that the battery was encapsulated in the laptop, so I had to disassemble it to remove the battery. Try first removing the battery from your Ipad and running it with charger only.